# Finding the most efficient way to batch combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of integers S (numbered from 0 to n-1) of size n. I have a batch size of k (k<<n). Now there are exactly $_n C_2$ pairs of distinct integers in S - call this set $C_n$. Assume k a multiple of n.

I want to find j groups of size k each such that:

- for each group $G_i$, where $i<j$, there are exactly k distinct integers
- there are $_k C_2$ pairs of distinct integers in group $G_i$ - call this set $P_i$ (contains pairs of integers)
- the union of all $P_i$ is equal to $C_n$. i.e. $\cup_{i=0}^{j-1} P_i = C_n$
- j is as small as possible

i.e. I want to find the smallest set of groups that have these properties.

I get the feeling that some sort of fancy indexing should do the trick but so far I've not found anything satisfactory. Hopefully this is an easily solved problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a special case of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4184811/combinatorics-sets-min-number-of-items-from-combinations-that-when-generate/4185339#4185339), when their $K=2$.

Comment: Thanks - was wondering why i couldn't get an exact answer. When $K=1$, the problem is trivial - was hoping perhaps that the special case of $K=2$ would have an exact solution but alas.