# Arrange to have all pairs

Tags: combinatorics

You have `N` groups of items. Items are the same in the same group, but different between groups.

You want to arrange them on the shelves of the shelving unit so that each of the possible pairs of different items appears on at least one shelf. Each shelf holds `M` items. You may leave some free slots on the shelf if you want.

You have a shortage of shelves, so you want to minimize amount of occupied shelves.

For `N`=6, `M`=3, one of the optimal arrangements looks like this:

```
1 2 3
1 4 5
1 5 6
2 3 5
2 4 6
3 4 6
```

6 shelves to display all possible pairs, you can not go lower than this.

Theoretical minimum amount can be calculated as $W=\Large\frac{С_N^M}{\sum_{i=0}^{M-1}{i}}$, for an example above it is $W={\Large\frac{\frac{6!}{(6-2)!*2!}}{0+1+2}}=5$

And it is always lower, than real. It is reasonable, you need to have some items duplicated. Question is – is there a way to calculate real minimum amount, and maybe even algorithmic way to arrange items in a best possible way?

If there is – I have another variant of the same task, a harder one (maby not).

... You want to arrange them on the shelves of the shelving unit so that each of the possible **groups of `K`** of different items appears on at least one shelf. ... where `K` <= `M` of course.

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to include this into the question itself, so I'll just add a comment.

I have a python script, which tries to solve this by trying different arrangements. 
It finds an answer of 1502 for `N`=165 and `M`=5. Theoretical answer for this is 902. And I can't see if my answer is good or not, cos I don't know how to calculate the real minimum.

Comment: A trivial lower bound on the number of shelves required is $\lceil{n \choose 2}/m\rceil$. Under what circumstances would that many not be enough?

Comment: The variant at the end is a duplicate of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4184811/177399 Perhaps you can say something more specific when you are just talking about covering pairs, I’m not sure.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum it's too broad for big M values, for example for N=70, M=10, it gives 241, actual best arrangement is 60, and my formula gives 53.

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks for the lead! I'll go learn more about those covering designs

Comment: According to your formula for the theoretical minimum, it is 35/3 when N=7 and M=3. On the contrary, there is an arrangement with only 7 shelves. I can suggest a theoretical minimum of [N(N-1)/2]/[M(M-1)/2], as each shelf has mC2 pairs, so if there is no repetition this should work.